# How to manually select(highlight) item from navigation drawer in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

The navigation drawer code is as follows:

```
private void ShowNavigationDrawer() {

    // DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Populate the Navigtion Drawer with options
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer_white, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close);

    // Drawer Item click listeners
    mDrawerList
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    selectItemFromDrawer(position);
                }
            });
}
```

The other used methods are:

```
/*
 * Called when a particular item from the navigation drawer is selected.
 */
private void selectItemFromDrawer(int position) {
    selectItem(position);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mNavItems.get(position).mTitle);

    // Close the drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

To select the correct fragment to load within one activity:

```
/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 1:
        currentFragment = new ABCFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        currentFragment = new SearchTabFragment();
        break;

    default:
        currentFragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    }

    currentFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content_frame, currentFragment);

    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

To select(highlight) the particular item from the navigation drawer programatically within another fragment I'm calling the following method but it is NOT working!

```
// Highlight the selected item
homeActivity.mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Where is the problem? Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: By manually you mean programatically highlight yes?

Comment: Yes, programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since highlighting means giving it a background color as you want. If you do not want it in the click event of items but want it otherwise, you have to give it manually on your navigation drawer adapter. like this

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
        if(position==0)
        {
           holder.llnavdrawer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        }
        else if(position==2)
        {
            holder.llnavdrawer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);
        }
        else if(position==4)
        {
            holder.llnavdrawer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        }
        else if(position==6)
        {
            holder.llnavdrawer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        }

    }
```

you can ask if the thing you wanted is not this.
Good luck!!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to implement the navigation drawer with the new NavigationView instead of the ListView. Something like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv_navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_item_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_item_selector"
    app:itemBackground="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

You can populate the NavigationView with a menu .xml file. Then you can easily select programmatically an item like this:

```
 mNavigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.my_item_1);
```

and the drawable selector will handle the work of the highlighting in the correct manner. For example, this is my selector (navigation_item_selector.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

PS I know its not the solution that you want, but its the solution that you might find helpful.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that your `MenuItem` must be declared as `checkable` to have this working, otherwise `mNavigationView.setCheckedItem` will be ignored.